# How to use environment variable PROGRAMFILES(X86) in a GNU makefile?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, gnu-make

I try to use the environment variable PROGRAMFILES(X86) of Windows 7 inside a GNU makefile without success.

Here a minimal example:

```
$(info DIR: $(PROGRAMFILES(X86)))
nop:
    @echo x
```

If I execute this makefile I get only

```
DIR: )
x
```

while I expected:

```
DIR: C:\Program Files (x86)
x
```

Any idea how to use environment variable PROGRAMFILES(X86) in a GNU makefile?

I am using GNU make version 4.1 on Cygwin (and version 3.81 on native Windows).
I know that that there is also and environment variable "PROGRAMFILES", but I really need "PROGRAMFILES(X86)"

Comment: If you run `make -qp` do you see that variable in the list of variables make knows about?

Comment: On Unix systems, environment variable names do not normally include punctuation such as parentheses.  You're treading on thin ice using such a name as an environment variable — and I'm assuming you are actually managing to create such a variable, though I have some doubts about that: `export 'A(C)'=aleph-null` generates `-bash: export: 'A(C)=aleph-null': not a valid identifier` from Bash 3.2 on Mac OS X 10.11.3 (but `export 'AC'=aleph-null` works fine, of course, so it isn't the single quotes causing the trouble).

Comment: @Etan: In the output of "make -qp" it's there named as "ProgramFiles(x86)", which is strange, since normally Cygwin's make translates all environment variables to upper case. Anyway, no matter which casing I am using I don't get access to the environment variable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is Windows. All common sense and sanity is long since gone. =)

Comment: @Jonathan: I totally agree that using parentheses in the name of an environment variable is the worst idea ever. However it is not my idea. Microsoft came up with this clever idea. So somehow I have to go on with this crazy thing.

Comment: You could try using `lp := (` and then using `$(info DIR: $(PROGRAMFILES$(lp)X86))` and seeing if that works. I don't have a cygwin environment to test it on. If that doesn't work you could try with `rp := )` also and see if that helps.

Comment: Very nice idea. Putting both left and right parentheses in macros work. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Etan came up with a very nice idea. 
I did a slight modification and thus, the following actually works:

```
b1 := (
b2 := )
$(info DIR: $(ProgramFiles$(b1)x86$(b2)) )
nop:
    @echo x
```

However I figured out a more easy way: Curly braces seem to do the trick too:

```
$(info DIR: ${ProgramFiles(x86)} )
nop:
    @echo x
```

For both solutions it is also important to write `ProgramFiles(x86)` instead of upper case `PROGRAMFILES(X86)`.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call this _nice_, let alone _pretty_, but if it's a feasible workaround it's worth an upvote 